# Manage almost 3.5 PB/3500 TB of data

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, cassandra, bigdata, greenplum

I am looking at an opportunity wherein we will have to manage almost 3.5 PB/3500 TB of data. From what I have read so far, GreenPlum seems to be a good choice. Having said that I am struggling to find a good resource to give me an idea around the Hardware requirements. Following are the base inputs on which we are building this:

1). Data would be coming in at rate of 2 GBps (Giga BYTE)
2). The data is fairly simple with only one large table with 15 odd columns. Each column/record would be close to 2 KB
3). I would need indexing on 6 columns. Each of these columns is a varchar/string column 
4). The use case is more write intensive and less of read intensive. The idea would be to process a set of 15-20 batch jobs per day. Real/Near real time analytics is not a necessity. This is more from a reporting purpose.
5). Data is time series data and would be required for a month. So data older than a month would be purged.

What I have udnerstood so far is that GreenPlum recommends 2x8 cores(Threads) and 256 GB RAM per host. Also each host should typically looks at 24 slots of hard disk. If I look at ESAS with 4TB each I should be able to host 96 TB / host.If I assume a simple linear extrapolation I would be looking at (3500 / 96 ) 37 nodes.

Now I know its not that simple/linear a calculation. Hence, I wanted to udnerstand if there is any calculator/resource/guidelines to size the database cluster. Also I wanted to know if it is ok to not give dedicated disks to the server and rather use a single SAN storage. Each server can have 2x10G links to make sure easy data transfers between nodes and SAN.

Many Thanks.

Abhi

Comment: If you want to keep that many data in a database *and* run queries efficiently, I'd say forget it. You need one system to ingest the data and an ETL process to extract the data into a much smaller data warehouse where you run your queries.

Answer (score 2):

You likely won't need indexes because of the architecture of Greenplum.  You will just need to use good partitioning which your design suggests.

Leveraging the cluster for data transformation is also a great idea and a common use case for Greenplum.

> What I have udnerstood so far is that GreenPlum recommends 2x8 cores(Threads) and 256 GB RAM per host.

By "threads", I'm assuming you mean "Segments" and your statement isn't completely accurate.  The number of Segments per host depends on how much RAM, cores, and disk performance each Segment host will have in addition to the level of concurrency.

I would use a minimum of 8GB of RAM, 4 cores, and 100 MB/s of disk performance per segment.  And 100 MB/s of disk performance is definitely on the low end.  It will be a balancing act of getting the number of segments per host right.

One way to do this is with the TPC-DS benchmark.  https://github.com/pivotalguru/tpc-ds
You can run the benchmark, get the results, reinitialize the cluster to use more/less segments per host, and then run the test again.  You can also set the level of concurrency in the test that best matches what you are expecting.

> Also I wanted to know if it is ok to not give dedicated disks to the server and rather use a single SAN storage. Each server can have 2x10G links to make sure easy data transfers between nodes and SAN.

SAN is usually configured with IOPs in mind and not throughput which Greenplum needs.  With that much data, you are usually better off with DAS.  Some cloud vendors provide pretty good throughput to their SAN solutions but you end up having to run many, small nodes to get the overall throughput you want.

Comment: For the size estimation, you need to consider workfile and mirror spaces.

Comment: also you will need to pick the right index for your text data type, but Jon Roberts is right. You really should not use index. once you create index, your writing performance will be dropped (creating index). based on your use case, daily partition  with column oriented append only table makes sense.